# export / import : metadata missing

Tags: 2013, document-library

I have a document library with 3000 documents and its upto 3 gb . I tried to use import / export command to move data from one environment to another, but could find some metadata missing . Just wanted to know why the metadata is missing ? Is there a way to migrate 3gb of doc lib maintaining the metadata as is ?